# Изменить все строки подходящие под шаблон в файле с помощью команд Linux

Tags: linux, строки, bash, sed, grep

Можете подсказать как это сделать с помощью команд Linux и Bash?
Есть файл и в нем есть строки по типу:
`some_string = Argc("data")`
И дан шаблон замены `Argc("some_string")` на `Argv"some_string"`, т.е. заменить все вхождения Argc на Argv и убрать скобочки
и после выполнения скрипта должно стать
`some_string = Argv"data"`

Comment: Из того что я понял нужно что то на подобии этого`sed -r '/^some_string/s/Argc\("[^"]+"\)/Argv"\1"/' file`

Answer (score 1):

подозреваю, что тот, кто давал вам задание, предполагал, что вы воспользуетесь «старым добрым» m4. нет, не тем, который носят на ремне:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а тем который [макропроцессор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4_(%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80)).

---

создадим файл с правилом преобразования (имена таких правил принято сопровождать суффиксом `.m4`):

```
$ cat r.m4
define(Argc,Argv$1)dnl
```

ну а исходный файл пусть будет таким:

```
$ cat foo 
bar
some_string = Argc("data")
```

если теперь программе *m4* передать эти файлы, так:

```
$ m4 r.m4 foo
```

или так:

```
$ cat r.m4 foo | m4
```

то получим вот такой результат:

```
bar
some_string = Argv"data"
```

тут главное, чтобы правило преобразования встретилось раньше той информации, которую надо преобразовывать.